# Halt the controller and wait for the service response

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-services

I am having trouble with service in angular js. As service are asynchronous (fire and forget) whatever the success value comes i want it in my controller for further operations. Are there any solution. Any examples

Comment: declare a callback in the controller, give it to the service you use, and the callback will be fired once the service has done its work. You don't really have the choice.

Comment: You can use "resolve" from the routing object you are using.

Comment: @PierreEmmanuelLallemant could you give me any example of call back as ans.

Comment: Any ways thanks i found the solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see that you already have found a solution. But I would recommend using deferred.

You can read more [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) about the documentation.